iOS Swift Task.sleep accuracy
I was looking into a cancellable async delay in Swift which is backwards compatible to iOS 15:
Task {
    let before = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    
    let seconds: TimeInterval = 100
    print("> sleeping for \(seconds) seconds...")
    
    try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(seconds * 1_000_000_000))
    
    let after = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
    
    print(String(format: "> slept for %0.3f seconds", after - before))
}

This solution using Task.sleep works fine, but it seems to be rather inaccurate for longer delays.
Running on iOS 16 simulator yields this:
> sleeping for 20.0 seconds...
> slept for 21.332 seconds

> sleeping for 60.0 seconds...
> slept for 63.995 seconds

> sleeping for 100.0 seconds...
> slept for 106.662 seconds

Is there a better way to achieve this?

I know that you asked about iOS 15 (in which case you have to fall back to some legacy technique, as Bram demonstrated), but for future readers, in iOS 16+, one would just try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(seconds), tolerance: .zero).

Yes, thank you for pointing that out. This will provide the same high accuracy as the GCD timer.

To enjoy more accurate sleep duration, one would specify a leeway/tolerance. In iOS 16+, you have sleep(for:tolerance:clock:):
try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(seconds), tolerance: .zero)

As suggested by Bram, if you need to support iOS 15, you can write your own rendition using, for example, a DispatchSourceTimer. But, specify a setCancelHandler to detect/handle the cancellation of the timer:
@available(iOS,     deprecated: 16.0, renamed: "Task.sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)")
@available(macOS,   deprecated: 13.0, renamed: "Task.sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)")
@available(watchOS, deprecated: 9.0,  renamed: "Task.sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)")
@available(tvOS,    deprecated: 16.0, renamed: "Task.sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)")
func sleep(for interval: DispatchTimeInterval, leeway: DispatchTimeInterval) async throws {
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: (Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier ?? "sleep") + ".timer", qos: .userInitiated)
    let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)

    try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) in
            guard !Task.isCancelled else {
                continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
                return
            }

            timer.schedule(
                deadline: .now() + interval,
                repeating: .never,
                leeway: leeway
            )

            timer.setEventHandler {
                continuation.resume()
            }

            timer.setCancelHandler {
                continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
            }

            timer.activate()
        }
    } onCancel: {
        timer.cancel()
    }
}

extension DispatchTimeInterval {
    static var zero: DispatchTimeInterval { .nanoseconds(0) }
}

And you would call it like so:
try await sleep(for: .seconds(10), leeway: .zero)

This throws CancellationError if the task is cancelled (like the Task.sleep API).
Also, if you promote the minimum target OS at some future date to a version that supports the tolerance variation, the above will produce a warning, suggesting the use of the contemporary API.

As an obligatory aside, the reason that timers and sleep API even have a leeway/tolerance is to afford the coalescing of events to minimize power drain on the device. So one might be best advised to only narrow the tolerance where the app truly requires that, with the recognition of the battery/power implications.

Forgive original rendition, in which I used Duration (which was introduced in iOS 16). Switched to DispatchTimeInterval.

Hi, thanks for your input. Now this looks very sophisticated. Anyway, Duration is only available on iOS 16.

Oh, you read my thoughts.

func accurateDelay(seconds: TimeInterval) async throws {
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default)
    let timer = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource(queue: queue)
    
    try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        try await withCheckedThrowingContinuation { (continuation: CheckedContinuation<Void, Error>) in
            if Task.isCancelled {
                timer.cancel()
                return continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
            }
            
            timer.schedule(deadline: .now() + seconds, leeway: .nanoseconds(1))
            
            timer.setEventHandler { [weak timer] in
                if Task.isCancelled {
                    continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
                } else {
                    continuation.resume()
                }
                timer?.cancel()
            }
            
            timer.activate()
            if Task.isCancelled {
                timer.cancel()
                continuation.resume(throwing: CancellationError())
            }
        }
    } onCancel: {
        timer.cancel()
    }
}

A DispatchSourceTimer can be used to execute something more accurately I suppose. The below example gave me something quite accurate.
struct AccurateTimerView: View {
    let delay: TimeInterval
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            Task {
                let before = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
                await accurateDelay(seconds: delay)
                let after = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
                print(String(format: "> slept for %0.3f seconds", after - before))
            }
        }, label: {
            Text("Start")
        })
    }
}

#Preview {
    VStack {
        AccurateTimerView(delay: 20)
        AccurateTimerView(delay: 60)
        AccurateTimerView(delay: 100)
    }
}

> slept for 20.001 seconds
> slept for 60.000 seconds
> slept for 99.999 seconds


Thank you very much for your answer! But the GCD timer won't automatically cancel with the Swift Concurrency Task. I guess that's why there is Task.sleep(until:, tolerance:, clock:) in iOS 16. A custom implementation (e.g. using GCD) is probably necessary for earlier versions.

@neatchuck I've updated the answer to implement the requested cancel behavior if I'm not mistaken

Wow, thanks for your effort. There's a lot going on now.

@Bram - I upvoted, but we should note that this does not throw CancellationError if the accurateDelay is cancelled after it was started. If you cancel the timer, the closure is never called. You need to use setCancelHandler if you want to detect this.

@Rob good spot, I did add that previously, forgot to add it again here
